# Running process in hidden mode

Tags: java

How do I run external process in hidden mode (no windows should be visible) in Java. I googled  and found that this can be done in .NET using the following code:

```
Dim ProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo
ProcessProperties.FileName = "notepad"
ProcessProperties.Arguments = "myTextFile.txt"
ProcessProperties.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start(ProcessProperties)
```

Is there any similar features provided for Java?

Comment: This is not C#.  Look more like VB.

Comment: yah, here is the link http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/prstrt.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is javaw what you are looking for?

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)

> The javaw command is identical to
>   java, except that with javaw there is
>   no associated console window. Use
>   javaw when you don't want a command
>   prompt window to appear. The javaw
>   launcher will, however, display a
>   dialog box with error information if a
>   launch fails for some reason.

Comment: No, Running external process like notepad or some thing which has window in hidden mode.

Comment: Nice to get answer accepted, but I'm confused. Using javaw will not result in hidden child process window if you, say, exec Notepad.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) to start the process.

If it's a Java application, you can start it with [javaw](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) to avoid a window.